# set Range property

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have written a code for setting the range property , and it is working properly for some moment.
example below is my code.

```
row_no = Ydim1 * matrix - Ydim1 + matrix
Set rng1 = Range("A" & row_no & ":" & c & row_no).Find(What:=somevar, LookIn:=xlValues,      Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

if Ydim1 is equal to 72 and matrix  is equal to 1 then row equal to 1 and c ="EO" then It will work correct
if ydim1 is equal to 74 and matrix =1 then also row_no =1 only but rng1 shows nothing

thank you in advance

Comment: When testing fully identify the range object. eg: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row_no .....`. Just in case.

Comment: are you sure that whatever `somevar` is actually exists between A1 and EO1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to debugging.

Use

```
debug.print "A" & row_no & ":" & c & row_no
```

to Check if your range is properly set, and check that all row numbers > 0.
Also use

```
debug.print somevar
```

to check on your lookup value.
In this particular case it would be ok to use .select in debug mode to visually check on your range.

You can achieve a similar result, using the immediate window cmd

```
print <variablename>
? <variablename> 'This is the same, represented by a question mark
```

in debug mode with a breakpoint after the line that you want to debug).

If you follow these steps, I'm quite positive that you will find the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can help you, but it would not be more simple if you use the Offset property, like

```
   Set rng1 = Range(Range("A1").Offset(row_no,0), Range("EO").Offset(rowno,0)).Find(What:=somevar, LookIn:=xlValues,Lookat:=xlWhole)
```